# CDK create resource if does not exist - typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

Created a dynamoDB table in my CDK project. this is fine it is used by lambdas created in the project. We needed to delete the stack which is also fine as we have retain resource set to true on the table.

Now when I try a fresh deploy we get table already exists error and stack rolls back. I need code that will create the table only if it does not exist.

Here is basic creation of a table, i cannot find any documentation anywhere on this issue or even an exception that can be caught or where i can see the type of exception that gets thrown to catch as we only see logs in the cloudformation console on AWS console.

```
 const dynamoTable = new Table(this, "my-table", {
      tableName: StackConfiguration.tableName,
      partitionKey: { name: "id", type: AttributeType.STRING },
    });
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth to look into the static methods that are part of the Table, e.g. `static fromTableName(scope, id, tableName)`.  With those you can bring "external"/ existing tables into the CDK app.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't do that in CDK, because CDK generates CloudFormation template at compile time, not at runtime. I see several options here:

1. Use [CloudFormation Resource Import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) to import existing table into your stack
2. Use Custom resource lambda to do an AWS API call to check if table exists. Use Custom resource output in `Fn.conditionEquals` in CDK code to create table conditionally

I would recommend going with first option if it's a one-off thing you need to do, and option 2 if you expect this to happen regularly.

Answer (score -4):

This isn't a great answer but a workaround, I will leave it here incase it might be of use to someone but we can add the table creation into a try catch in our code, I just caught a general exception rather than a specific one i would be interested if anyone had the correct exception to catch here. This means the stack will deploy.

```
 try {
     const dynamoTable = new Table(this, "my-table", {
      tableName: StackConfiguration.tableName,
      partitionKey: { name: "id", type: AttributeType.STRING },
    });
    
      return dynamoReplayTable;
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
```

If you want to use the table then in your code you will need to reference the ARN rather than the table variable name or else you could do some import from name thing in the catch block. But the best solution I have found is keep the tables in a separate stack.

Comment: This is not how CDK works.  The only way an exception would get thrown there is if you were passing incorrect arguments to the Table constructor.

Comment: This does work though where the stack would normally fails because already resource exists, it now passes cause exception was caught

Comment: I just tested this and it does not work.  If the resource already exists, it already exists.  CDK works in two steps.  1. is the creation of the cloud assembly which is template files for stacks from the app code.  This is the only time the app code runs.  2. Is to deploy the generated assembly to the account using CloudFormation.

If the app code says to create a dynamo table with name "ABC" then the template file will be configured to create it with name "ABC".   Exception handling does not carry over to the template files.  CDK code does not execute during CloudFormation deployment.

Comment: Honestly was sure this deployed for me, like it went to create the table in a try block, must of bombed out cause it already exists and then continued on with the code. I've moved on from this now so can't test but I will take you lr word for it

Comment: What you are saying makes sense actually yea but was sure that worked. You seem to know a bit around CDK could you check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637238/cdk-s3-notification-causing-cyclic-reference-error

Comment: `cdk deploy` will first build the Cloudformation equivalent template. The throwing part happens because the `template` was built, then AWS tries to create the resource, and it throws.

Comment: I have the same problem. There must be a solution. What's the point of creating a resource with RETAIN to prevent data loss, and then not able to deploy changes. I just want my lambdas deployed and not delete my timestream, dynamodb, cognito. I had to add more permissions to the lambda and I got trapped. The only solution I have used so far is splitting into multiple CDK pipelines. One for timestream, one for dynamo, then import the ARNs into the lambda CDK and bind them there. But terrible as I want a mono repo. Any real suggestions?