# CDK - S3 notification causing cyclic reference error

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I want to create an S3 bucket in one stack, pass it into another and then use it to create a notification onto an sns or sqs. Here is an example of broken down code would look like.

stack 1

```
export class BucketStack extends BaseStack {

  public readonly mynBucket: Bucket;


  constructor(scope: App, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    const properties: StackProps = {
      env: {
        region: StackConfiguration.region,
      },
    };
    super(scope, id, properties);
    this.myBucket = this.createMyBucket();
  }


  private createMyBucket() {
   // create and return bucket
}
```

stack 2

```
import * as s3n from '@aws-cdk/aws-s3-notifications';

export class ServiceStack extends BaseStack {
  constructor(scope: App, id: string, myBucket: Bucket) {
    const properties: StackProps = {
      env: {
        region: StackConfiguration.region,
      },
    };

    super(scope, id, properties);

    const topic = new Topic(this, 'Topic');
  
    myBucket.addEventNotification(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_PUT, new s3n.SnsDestination(topic));
```

Error is
`Error: 'my-bucket-stack' depends on 'my-service-stack' (Depends on Lambda resources., Depends on resources.). Adding this dependency (my-service-stack -> my-bucket-stack/myBucket/Resource.Arn) would create a cyclic reference.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates, that you use a Lambda.

Where is that Lamdba definition?

What are you trying to do with SNS?

I assume that you wanted to apply the pattern (S3 PUT -> Notification -> Lambda) because you didn't post the full code (including the Lambda) itself.

Proceeding with my assumption, let me show you the issue what you're currently facing:
[image: Circular Dependency between Bucket and Lambda (Role)]

Plain Cloud Formation, which is being used under the hood with CDK, can't tackle that by itself and you would need to create a Custom Resource to overcome this issue.
AWS CDK can tackle this though, because it's creating the required Custom Resource and the correct creation sequence automatically!

Instead of using the `s3n.SnsDestination`, use the Lambda Destination as shown in the snippet. You can easily extract everything in separate stacks, because the issue shouldn't be with separating stacks.

```js
export class TestStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const bucket = new Bucket(this, "your-bucket-construct-id",{
       // ...
    });

     // Lambda
    const lambda = new Function(this, 'the-triggered-lambda', {
      code: Code.asset(path.join(__dirname,  '../src/your-lambda-folder')),
      handler: 'index.handler',
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
    });

    // S3 -> Lambda
    bucket.addEventNotification(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_PUT, new LambdaDestination(lambda));
  }
}
```

Let me know, if that's answering your question or if you're facing any issues.

Comment: Think it is due to a bug in CDK code check out the issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11245

Seems to be resolved with Lambda destination as I can see they resolved a similar bug here https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5760

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer anyway as it the only viable solution to the problem at this moment in time as is well documented.