# How to create else reference resources in AWS CDK in CI/CD?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I’m curious about how to use CI/CD in conjunction with AWS CDK; specifically, I want need a pattern where if a given resource does not yet exist, it is created else the (therefore existing) resource is referenced.

Here is an attempt to create a DynamoDb table if it does not exist else reference it. I’m curious, is this the correct/canonical way to do this?

```js
const existingTable = dynamodb.Table.fromTableName(stack, 'ExistingTable', 'existing-table-name');

const table = new dynamodb.Table(stack, 'MyTable', {
  tableName: 'my-table',
  partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
  // Define other table attributes
});

if (!existingTable.tableArn) {
  // Create the table if it doesn't exist
  table.create();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CDK create resource if does not exist - typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598439/cdk-create-resource-if-does-not-exist-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something you can do only using CDK. CDK is not a library that interacts with AWS resource APIs by default (there are some exceptions, such as the functions that generally start with `lookup*`). It is a library that generates CloudFormation templates. Those templates do not have the ability to "create a resource if it doesn't exist" semantic.

You have a few options here:

1. You can use the AWS SDK libraries to do the lookup yourself. While this will often work, keep in mind it isn't fool-proof. It is susceptible to Time-of-check-time-of-use (TOCTOU) errors, where the resource did/didn't exist at the time the template was synthesized, but was later created/removed by something else.
2. You can use a Custom Resource, which would do the check and create using the libraries. This is similarly finicky (and custom resources are notoriously difficult to get right).
3. You can add a configuration option to your context, where you specify the table name and/or ARN of the table. Then you would conditionally create the resource or use the `fromTableName`/`fromTableArn` methods. This is my personal preference, and where appropriate I use this pattern.

Keep in mind that, generally speaking, this is an anti-pattern. You should know at deploy-time whether you are are using an existing resource or creating a new one. Having it dynamically detect and change what is deployed opens you up to errors/unexpected behavior, up to and including data loss:

1. What happens if the existing table happens to be deleted by some other resource? A new table will be created when you update. That table will be owned by some new stack, and not contain the data that is expected. Similarly, if this stack is being deployed more than once in an account, the next owner of the table will depend on whoever deploys next (which is likely unexpected).
2. You have no inherent dependency on the table. Related to #1, a better pattern would be to use an `Fn::ImportValue` to ensure there is a dependency between two stacks, where one provides the table and the other uses it.

Comment: From what you’ve explained, it sounds that the CDK ts file will be a living, breathing document and is expected to change with virtually every deployment (whereas, this is not the case, for example, in the context of a React App, where you’d only update the package/files if changes to the app were desired.) Is this a fair conclusion?

Comment: Your CDK ts file is more of a file generator. CDK is a DSL (domain specific language) that can be used to generate CloudFormation in a more dynamic way (CFN normally being simple yaml/json, so no options for using loops, local if'else closes, or data/configuration files). When you run `cdk deploy`, the runtime converts your CDK into one or more json files (this is called "synthesis"). It will then actually upload the template/assets to CloudFormation, where CloudFormation does the real work. Every time you run `cdk deploy`, it is re-synthesized (and thus could change).

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare if you need to iteratively deploy changes to an application, especially a monolith. However, potentially less painful in a micro service context where each service’s resources have minimal overlap with other services’ resources. So changes to CDK for a given micro service would require fewer lines of code.

Comment: I'm curious why you think that. To be clear, just because the template is re-generated does not mean re-deployment of the monolith results in more work. Again CDK is a template generator. You have the full power of your chosen programming language, allowing you to write templates that are far more succinct. Just don't forget that you are not writing code that directly calls APIs. You are generate a template that is later used by CloudFormation (i.e., your imperative code is turned into a declarative configuration file and executed by something else).

Comment: CDK does support a "hotswap" mode that, where appropriate, calls APIs directly. This is useful in development, as it avoids going through CFN, which can be slower to iterate on. Check out `cdk watch` and `cdk --hotswap`.